# JAGS: variable number of clusters

Tags: r, jags, rjags

I am trying to run a Bayesian clustering model where the number of clusters is random with binomial distribution.
This is my Jags model:

```
model{
    for(i in 1:n){
        y[ i ,1:M] ~ dmnorm( mu[z[i] , 1:M] , I[1:M, 1:M])      
        z[i] ~ dcat(omega[1:M])
    }
    for(j in 1:M){
        mu[j,1:M] ~ dmnorm( mu_input[j,1:M] , I[1:M, 1:M] )
    }
    M ~ dbin(p, Mmax)       
    omega ~ ddirich(rep(1,Mmax))
}
```

to run it, we need to define the parameters anche the initial values for the variables, which is done in this R script

```
Mmax=10

y = matrix(0,100,Mmax)
I = diag(Mmax)
y[1:50,] = mvrnorm(50, rep(0,Mmax), I)
y[51:100,] = mvrnorm(50, rep(5,Mmax), I)

plot(y[,1:2])

z = 1*((1:100)>50) + 1

n = dim(y)[1]

M=2
mu=matrix(rnorm(Mmax^2),nrow=Mmax)
mu_input=matrix(2.5,Mmax,Mmax) ### prior mean
p=0.5

omega=rep(1,Mmax)/Mmax

data = list(y = y, I = I, n = n, mu_input=mu_input, Mmax = Mmax, p = p)

inits = function() {list(mu=mu,
                         M=M,
                         omega = omega) }

require(rjags)
modelRegress=jags.model("cluster_variabile.txt",data=data,inits=inits,n.adapt=1000,n.chains=1)
```

however, running the last command, one gets

```
Error in jags.model("cluster_variabile.txt", data = data, inits = inits,
:   RUNTIME ERROR: Compilation error on line 6. 
Unknown variable M Either supply values 
for this variable with the data or define it  on the left hand side of a relation.
```

which for me makes no sense, since the error is at line 6 even if M already appears at line 4 of the model! What is the actual problem in running this script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So JAGS is not like R or other programming procedural languages in that it doesn't actually run line by line, it is a declarative language meaning the order of commands doesn't actually matter at least in terms of how the errors pop up. So just because it didn't throw an error on line 4 doesn't mean something isn't also wrong there. Im not positive, but I believe the error is occuring because JAGS tries to build the array first before inputting values, so M is not actually defined at this stage, but nothing you can do about that on your end.

With that aside, there should be a fairly easy work around for this, it is just less efficient. Instead of looping from `1:M` make the loop iterate from `1:MMax` that way the dimensions don't actually change, it is always an MMax x MMax. Then line 7 just assigns 1:M of those positions to a value. The downside of this is that it will require you to do some processing after the model is fit. So on each iteration, you will need to pull the sampled M and filter the matrix mu to be M x M, but that shouldn't be too tough. Let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 1):

So, I think the main problem  is that you can't change the dimensionality of the stochastic node you're updating.  This seems like a problem for reversible jump MCMC, though I don't think you can do this in JAGS.

Comment: This means that there is no solution?

Comment: I think not in JAGS.  It is possible to write a function that does update, but I am not confident that it gets the right answer. One way to think about the problem is that, for example, if M=2, you're updating the parameters related to 2 groups, relative to the data, but not the parameters relating to any other number of groups.  Would an almost as good alternative to be to estimate 10 different solutions and look at the DICs, or some other clustering statistic - for example C-H or the Gap statistic.  Having a posterior distribution on the # clusters would induce a posterior on these values.